# Making a GUI in Linux without booting the OS's GUI

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, pyqt

Sorry if I'm using wrong terminology here.

I'd like to make an appliance for users that's running from a Raspberry Pi. When it's booted, I'd like users to see my own GUI that I'll design (hopefully in PyQT but I'm not sure about that yet.)

The thing I don't know how to do: I don't want the users to see the Linux operating system on the screen at all. I don't want them to see the desktop and launch my app. I want my app to be automatically launched on startup. I want it to be the only thing accessible and visible to the users. i.e. it should be full-screen and a user wouldn't be able to exit it or interact with the OS in any way.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want something like a [kiosk screen](https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen-tutorial/)?

Comment: Compile Qt yourself with the EGLFS plattform plugin instead of using the standard xcb/wayland one. Then disable the GUI boot on your raspberry and launch your application instead. If you want to use pyside2, you can generate the bindings yourself from your self compiled Qt (not shure about pyqt though). See https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS to get started on compiling Qt for the raspberry